# kivy, как остановить музыку в SoundLoader, включаю музыку, но выключить почемуто не знаю как, подскажите как в киви останавливать музыку

Tags: python, kivy

делаю симулятор мобильной ОС и делаю проигрыватель с помощью функцию soundLoader в kivy, когда включаю музыку ее никак не остановить помогите.